# How to use 'sum' in R with two conditions without filtering?

Tags: r

I want the sum of all cases that fulfill two conditions (related to two different columns). It can be done using

```
dataset %>%
 filter (column1 == 'condition1') %>%
 summarise (number = sum(column2 == 'condition2'))
```

What I don't understand is why does the following not give the same numerical result:

```
dataset %>%
 summarise (number = sum(column1 == 'condition1', column2 == 'condition2'))
```

If that's not the way of obtaining the number of cases that fulfill condition 1 and condition 2 with the function `sum`, is there any other way? And most importantly, why does that way not work as one would expect? What is it enumerating instead of the number of cases that fulfill both conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be simplified by using the logical expression of 'condition' to subset the 'column2' and then do the second comparison on that subset to create the logicl expression for `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>%
      summarise(number = sum(column2[column1 == 'condition1']
        == 'condition2', na.rm = TRUE))
```

NOTE: With `==`, one issue may come create a spoiler is the presence of `NA`.  The `==` returns `NA` for those elements that are `NA`.  So, inorder to counteract that, `na.rm = TRUE` in `sum` would be better

---

Or another option is `&`

```
dataset %>%
   summarise (number = sum(column1 == 'condition1' &
                           column2 == 'condition2', na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or another option is to specify the conditions in `filter` and get the `nrow`

```
dataset %>%
   filter(column1 == 'condition1', column2 == 'condition2') %>%
   nrow()
```

The issue with the `&` approach is that we may be looking for corresponding rows where both are TRUE.  So, it could be the first logical expression where we are only looking for subset cases with 'condition2' is TRUE

---

NOTE: In `dplyr::filter`, if we pass multiple logical expressions separated by `,`, it is regarded as an `AND` (`&`) expression instead of a `|`, and that syntax is not translated in `summarise/mutate` as such.  There, we need to explicitly specify the `&` condition.

Also, `=` is an assignment operator and not a comparison (`==`)